# Replacing 2d array index if player position has values of a list

Tags: java

So right now when a player enters a position (pos) like A5 for example it will replace that board array index with the empty string if a ship isnt there. But if a ship is there I want it to replace it with the hitShip string.

```
public static void placePiece(String[][] board, String pos) {
        String empty = "0";
        String hitShip = "X";
        playerTargets.add(pos);

        switch (pos) {
            case "A1":
                board[1][2] = empty;
                break;
            case "B1":
                board[1][4] = empty;
                break;
            case "C1":
                board[1][6] = empty;
                break;
            case "D1":
                board[1][8] = empty;
                break;
            case "E1":
                board[1][10] = empty;
                break;
            case "F1":
                board[1][12] = empty;
                break;
            case "G1":
                board[1][14] = empty;
                break;
            case "H1":
                board[1][16] = empty;
                break;
            case "I1":
                board[1][18] = empty;
                break;
            case "J1":
                board[1][20] = empty;
                break;
```

And the switch case goes on for all coordinates (A1-J10)

ship1 has values "A6" & "A7" and ship2 has values "F1" & "F2".

```
 List ship1 = Arrays.asList(ar[0][0], ar[1][0]);
 List ship2 = Arrays.asList(ar[2][0], ar[3][0]);
```

I have this code to print hit/miss message depending on whether the player hit a ship but I'm not sure how I can use this to replace the board array's indexes with the hitShip variable.

```
// CHECKS IF THE PLAYER TARGETS HIT SHIP1
        boolean hit = false;
        for (Object string : ship1) {
            if (pos.contains((CharSequence) string)) {
                hit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // CHECKS IF THE PLAYER TARGETS HIT SHIP2
        for (Object string : ship2) {
            if (pos.contains((CharSequence) string)) {
                hit = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // PRINTS HIT/MISS MESSAGE DEPENDING ON WETHER THE PLAYER HIT A SHIP
        if (hit) {
            System.out.println("\nHit!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nMiss!!!");
        }
```

**EDITED code:**

```
 package intermediate;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.*;

public class Battleship {

    static ArrayList<String> playerTargets = new ArrayList<String>();

    private static String[][] ships;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String[][] board = {
                { " ", " ", "A", " ", "B", " ", "C", " ", "D", " ", "E", " ", "F", " ", "G", " ", "H", " ", "I", " ",
                        "J" },
                { "1", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "2", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "3", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "4", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "5", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "6", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "7", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "8", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "9", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " " },
                { "1", "0", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
                        " ", " " } };
        System.out.println("Let's Play Battleship!");
        printBoard(board);

        for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Choose your target Ex.(A3): ");
            String pos = scanner.next();

            while (playerTargets.contains(pos)) {
                System.out.println("Position taken! Please enter a valid position: ");
                pos = scanner.next();
            }

            placePiece(board, pos);
            String result = ships(board, pos);

            // ENDS THE PROGRAM IF USER HAS HIT ALL THE SHIPS
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                printBoard(board);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("You have " + (30 - i) + " missiles left");
            printBoard(board);
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(String[][] board) {
        for (String[] row : board) {
            for (String c : row) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static String ships(String[][] board, String pos) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // READS SHIP POSITIONS FROM SHIP FILE
        String filePath = "/Users/Otez/Desktop/ships.txt";
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] arr = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
                for (String item : arr) {
                    list.add(new String[] { item });
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[][] ar = list.toArray(String[][]::new);
        ships = new String[] {
                new String[] { ar[0][0], ar[1][0] },
                new String[] { ar[2][0], ar[3][0] }
        };

        // CHECKS IF THE PLAYER TARGETS HIT SHIP1
        boolean hit = false;
        for (Object string : ships) {
            if (pos.contains((CharSequence) string)) {
                hit = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // PRINTS HIT/MISS MESSAGE DEPENDING ON WHETHER THE PLAYER HIT A SHIP
        if (hit) {
            System.out.println("\nHit!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nMiss!!!");
        }

        // CHECKS IF PLAYER TARGETS HIT THE SHIPS ON THE BOARD
        if (playerTargets.containsAll(ships)) {
            return "YOU SANK MY ENTIRE FLEET!!!\n";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void placePiece(String[][] board, String pos) {
        String empty = "0";
        String hitShip = "X";
        playerTargets.add(pos);

        int firstIndex = Character.getNumericValue(pos.charAt(1));
        int secondIndex = (pos.charAt(0) - 64) * 2;
        board[firstIndex][secondIndex] = empty;
        String characterToPlace = empty;
        if (isShip(board, pos, ships)) {
            characterToPlace = hitShip;
        }
        board[firstIndex][secondIndex] = characterToPlace;
    }

    public static boolean isShip(String[][] board, String pos, String[][] ar) {
        for (String[] ship : ships) {
            for (String shipPos : ship) {
                if (shipPos.contains(pos)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last code you provide above could be placed right before "switch (pos)", but you would not want to break, as that would terminate the call to the mutator method "placePiece". "board" is a parameter and can not be modified outside the class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, writing and maintaining massive switch statements make for a not-so-elegant solution. The first thing I suggest you do, is clear up that code. Just from looking at it, I can see that as the letter in the first character of `pos` progresses through the alphabet, the second index you use on `board` increases by two.

So let's just resolve all this duplicate code using the magic of ASCII:

```java
public static void placePiece(String[][] board, String pos) {
    String empty = "0";
    String hitShip = "X";
    playerTargets.add(pos);

    int firstIndex = Character.getNumericValue(pos.charAt(1));
    int secondIndex = (pos.charAt(0) - 64) * 2;
    board[firstIndex][secondIndex] = empty;
}
```

Now whatever `pos` is, gets marked as empty. If I were you, I would now have a separate method which determines whether a ship was hit - it's good practice to try make your code more modular.

It seems to me that you don't really need to use lists, you could just use arrays for your ships:

```java
String[] ship1 = new String[] {ar[0][0], ar[1][0]};
String[] ship2 = new String[] {ar[2][0], ar[3][0]};

//and we'll have an array of all these ships just to make things easier
String[][] ships = new String[] {ship1, ship2};
```

These variables would ideally be global, because we don't need to keep creating them every time we check to see if the user has hit a ship.

Now we'll make a function to determine whether there is a ship at a location - remember, modular code is easier to change and maintain. I've written it very similarly to how you did, it just becomes shorter when using an array of ships.

```java
public static boolean isShip(String[][] board, String pos) {
    for (String[] ship : ships) {
        for (String shipPos : ship) {
            if (shipPos.contains(pos)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, we just incorporate our new `isShip` method into our rewritten `placePiece` method:

```java
public static void placePiece(String[][] board, String pos) {
    String empty = "0";
    String hitShip = "X";
    playerTargets.add(pos);

    int firstIndex = Character.getNumericValue(pos.charAt(1));
    int secondIndex = (pos.charAt(0) - 64) * 2;
    String characterToPlace = empty;
    if (isShip(board, pos)) {
        characterToPlace = hitShip;
    }
    board[firstIndex][secondIndex] = characterToPlace;
}
```

I've not tested the code but from looking at it, it should all work. From reading your code, I'd recommend you learn more about:

- Structuring your code in a modular way
- Writing 'clean' code

And I recommend holding off from using `List`s until you learn about generics.

EDIT: After our discussion in the comments, and reading your edited code. I suggest that instead of writing:

```java
String[] ship1 = new String[] { ar[0][0], ar[1][0] };
String[] ship2 = new String[] { ar[2][0], ar[3][0] };

String[][] ships = new String[] { ship1, ship2 };
```

that you instead write:

```java
private static String[][] ships;
```

and then in your `ships` method, after this line: `String[][] ar = list.toArray(String[][]::new);`, you could write the following:

```java
ships = new String[] {
    new String[] {ar[0][0], ar[1][0]},
    new String[] {ar[2][0], ar[3][0]}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm unable to make the ship arrays global because the ar[][] which I'm using to read the ship positions from a text file is declared in a method. I have edited the post and included my whole post, hope that helps.

Comment: @Otez you could also add an extra parameter to the `isShip` method so that it takes `ar[][]` as an argument. Then when you call `isShip` you can also send the ships to the method.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't quite solve the problem. `ar[][]` cannot be resolved globally inside the ships. I've tried making it global itself but that lead to a few more problems. I was wondering if we could have a proper conversation on another platform like Discord, Twitter etc.

Comment: @Otez I've made an edit to my post to accommodate your latest code changes. But I would still advising making your code more modular and breaking functionality out into multiple methods. I think you need to learn more about what `static` is and how it changes your interactions with code too.

Comment: I tried your new code and it says it cant read `ships`'s length due to it being null.

Comment: @Otez call the `ships` method at the start of your code and don't use it to check if a ship was hit by a move, you have another method for that now. The method should only load the ship data from files into the `ships` array.

Comment: placing a piece on coordinates up to 9 works but when I place a piece on a coordinate like C10 or F10 it places the piece on C1 or F1 instead. I'm assuming it has something to do with the ASCII code.

Comment: @Otez oh yeah, I didn't realise your board went that far. In which case, replace `Character.getNumericValue(pos.charAt(1))` with `Integer.parseInt(pos.substring(1))`

Comment: since I'm not using lists for the ships anymore how would I print a message if the player has hit all the ships in the `ships` array?

Comment: You could just scan the board for any ships or check all positions in the `ships` array or something

Comment: I added this new ship to the `ships` array `new String[] { ar[4][0], ar[5][0], ar[6][0] }` which has the coordinates `I8, I9, I10` but only `I8` is hittable. The other two coordinates print out miss and change to "0". I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: @Otez doesn't sound related to the original problem. I'd recommend debugging it yourself and making a new post if you're really stuck.